# Can't use Pydantic model attributes on type hinting

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, type-hinting, pydantic

Like I used to do with FastAPI routes, I want to make a function that is expecting a `dict`. I want to type hint like in FastAPI with a Pydantic model.

Note that I am just using FastAPI as a reference here and this app serves a total different purpose.

What I did:

`models.py`

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Mymodel(BaseModel):
  name:str
  age:int
```

`main.py`

```py
def myfunc(m:Mymodel):
  print(m)
  print(m.name)

myfunc({"name":"abcd","age":3})
```

It prints `m` as a normal dict and `not Mymodel` and `m.name` just throws an `AttributeError`.
I don't understand why it is behaving like this because the same code would work in FastAPI. Am I missing something here? What should I do to make this work.

I am expecting a `dict` arg in the func, I want to type hint with a class inherited from pydantic `BaseModel`. Then I want to acccess the attributes of that class.

I don't want to do:

```py
def myfunc(m):
  m = Mymodel(**m)
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic import validate_arguments

class Mymodel(BaseModel):
  name:str
  age:int

@validate_arguments
def myfunc(m:Mymodel):
   print(m)
   print(m.name)

myfunc({"name":"abcd","age":3})
```

This might be what you are looking for: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validation_decorator/

Answer (score 0):

Since you pass a `dict` to your custom function, the attribute should be accessed in the following way:

```py
print(m['name'])
# or
print(m.get('name'))
```

Otherwise, to use `m.name` instead, you need to parse the `dict` to the corresponding Pydantic model, before passing it to the function, as shwon below:

```
data = {"name":"abcd", "age":3}
myfunc(Mymodel(**data))
# or
myfunc(Mymodel.parse_obj(data))
```

The reason that passing `{"name":"abcd", "age":3}` in FastAPI and later accessing the attributes using the *dot* operator (e.g., `m.name`) works, is that FastAPI does the above parsing and validation internally, as soon as a request arrives. This is the reason that you can then convert it back to a dictionary in your endpoint, using `m.dict()`. Try, for example, passing an incorrect `key`, e.g., `myfunc(Mymodel(**{"name":"abcd","MYage":3}))`—you would get a `field required (type=value_error.missing)` error (as part of Pydantic's [Error Handling](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#error-handling)), similar to what FastAPI would return (as shown below), if a similar request attempted to go through (you could also test that through Swagger UI autodocs at http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs). Otherwise, any dictionary passed by the user (in the way you show in the question) would go through without throwing an error, in case it didn't match the Pydantic model.

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "age"
      ],
      "msg": "field required",
      "type": "value_error.missing"
    }
  ]
}
```

You could alternatively use Pydantic's validation decorator (i.e., `@validate_arguments`) on your custom function. As per the [documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validation_decorator/):

> The `validate_arguments` decorator allows the arguments passed to a
> function to be **parsed and validated** using the function's annotations
> before the function is called. While **under the hood this uses the same
> approach** of model *creation* and *initialisation*; it provides an
> extremely easy way to apply validation to your code with minimal
> boilerplate.

Example:

```py
from pydantic import validate_arguments
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Model(BaseModel):
  name: str
  age: int

@validate_arguments
def myfunc(m: Model):
   print(m)
   print(m.name)

myfunc({"name":"abcd","age":3})
```

Comment: but why is pydantic model not working like it works in FastAPI?

Comment: hi Chris, thanks for the quick response.
I already knew I could do that but you still didn't answer the main question which is why the same approach works for FastAPI routes and not working now.

Comment: ok, I guess I'll have to look into FastAPI's source. Thank you for your answer